# how to update view in a single item of recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

if each item of recycler view has multiple items (Button and textview)

I have interface to handle  Recycler's item click , I want upon clicking   Recycler view item ,  be able to update text view and button but from outside of the adapter class ,

how could I achieve this ? 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

call adapter.notifyItemChanged(position) on the adapter to change only a single object

EDIT: Based on your comment:

you don't need reference of textview. Just update the state of the item in the list at that position.
For exmaple, take a boolean, isclicked and mark it as true for position = x

Hadle the text and UI inside the onbindviewholder only based on the 
isClicked = true or false.

Comment: yes but my problem , how to get reference of textview so I can change color or text

Comment: you don't need reference of textview. Just update the state of the item in the list at that position. Hadle the text and UI inside the onbindviewholder only based on the item state

Comment: I didn't understand it well , inside that item , there are text view , I want to change the color , according to ur answer, "Just update the state of the item in the list at that position " , how could i update the color of text view if i don't have that reference

Answer (score 0):

You can use AdapterObject.NotifyDataSetChanged instead of setting the adapter again after the data in list gets updated.